# Visual Studio Adding Data Connections - Given Key not Present in the Dictionary

Tags: sql, visual-studio, server-explorer

I've read through a couple of previous similar questions and none seem to provide a fix. So I ask again.

I'm using Visual Studio and am trying to connect to a DB in Server Explorer.
Regardless of what database I try to connect to it gives a "Given Key not Present in the Dictionary" error.

I have tried with SQL CE and SQL Express 2008 databases and each give the same issue.

I can connect quite easily with SQL Management Studio Express so I believe the Databases are the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

after a lot of time searching for the answer to this i found the solution [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/572005/server-explorer-vs2010-data-connection-problem)

> this is not really a workaround but in fact a SOLUTION, how to get rid of the error, in case you have missed to remove all connections before removing the provider:
>
> edit C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ServerExplorer\DefaultView.SEView and remove the connection with the wrong Provider manually. If you do not know which of the provider is failing, simply delete the file :)
>
> If this won't help try deleting also C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0
>
> PS: you have to quit all instances of visual studios first or the files will be re-created from memory ..

The second part only worked for me , deleting the whole folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently installed the MySQL Connector, and had multiple instances of Visual Studio open.  After shutting them all down, I was able to add a connection to the Server Explorer.

Adding to what BastanteCaro said, I had open the `DefaultView.SEView` file in case I needed to go down that path.  When I shut everything down and started up a new instance of Visual Studio, Notepad++ reported that the file had changed.  So either there was an uncommitted change to the file or some sort of cleanup/addition was made on startup.