# "Configure Data Source with Wizard" doesn't want to open

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2017

I am building an application that connects to a mysql database.  I set up the data connections and data source (data set) and have begun working on development, going back and forth between adding tables and views to the database and adding forms and components to the application.

I have up to now used the "Configure Data Source with Wizard" wizard to refresh the dataset in the application.  Sometimes it takes a couple click throughs to get it to fully load the changes, but that's not the end of the world.

Today, without me knowingly changing anything, when I click on the wizard button, the frame of the wizard opens and closes instantly.

My data is accessible, and the parts of the application already developed work just fine, but I don't know how to add new tables and views to my project.  My worry is that something went screwy in one of the auto generated dbDataSet.* files.

I'm happy to provide more information if that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question for whomever comes here next:

I came across this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4749044/7640114

It links to a microsoft.com page that is no longer available, but copies the relevant information.  Finding the corresponding files is not hard, but knowing what the wrong Provider is may not be so simple.

Mostly because of a lack of patience, I just went with the second option and deleted the entire folder, which may have been overkill.  It worked, and I have access to the wizard again and can continue development, but it also wiped out my workspace layout which I now have to rebuild from my memory.

Win some/loose some.  In the end, I suggest being more delicate and removing lines of code from `DefaultView.SEView` first, and then moving on to trying to delete the file and the folder if nessasary.